# need to loop a process for unlimited characters in a batch file

Tags: loops, batch-file

I have a windows batch file which decodes a password I have (No narky comments its just to see how somthing works).

the password is read in from a file which is no problem, however im trying to decode it now which I would have no problem with except  for the fact that i dont know how to accomodate for an unkowen length of password characters.

the following works but only for a limited number of characters how can I program somthing simular for a password of an unknowen (unlimited) size?

if your wondering why the ~0,2 , because each letter in the alphabet is represented by a doubble numerical character set eg 00 represents A or 01 represents B thse are generated randomly in another program i built some while back.

```
IF %MYPASSWORD:~0,2% == %AA% msg * first letter is A
IF %MYPASSWORD:~0,2% == %BB% msg * first letter is B
IF %MYPASSWORD:~0,2% == %CC% msg * first letter is C
IF %MYPASSWORD:~0,2% == %DD% msg * first letter is D
IF %MYPASSWORD:~0,2% == %EE% msg * first letter is E
IF %MYPASSWORD:~0,2% == %FF% msg * first letter is F
IF %MYPASSWORD:~0,2% == %GG% msg * first letter is G
IF %MYPASSWORD:~0,2% == %HH% msg * first letter is H
IF %MYPASSWORD:~0,2% == %II% msg * first letter is I
IF %MYPASSWORD:~0,2% == %JJ% msg * first letter is J
IF %MYPASSWORD:~0,2% == %KK% msg * first letter is K
IF %MYPASSWORD:~0,2% == %LL% msg * first letter is L
IF %MYPASSWORD:~0,2% == %MM% msg * first letter is M
IF %MYPASSWORD:~0,2% == %NN% msg * first letter is N
IF %MYPASSWORD:~0,2% == %OO% msg * first letter is O
IF %MYPASSWORD:~0,2% == %PP% msg * first letter is P
IF %MYPASSWORD:~0,2% == %QQ% msg * first letter is Q
IF %MYPASSWORD:~0,2% == %RR% msg * first letter is R
IF %MYPASSWORD:~0,2% == %SS% msg * first letter is S
IF %MYPASSWORD:~0,2% == %TT% msg * first letter is T
IF %MYPASSWORD:~0,2% == %UU% msg * first letter is U
IF %MYPASSWORD:~0,2% == %VV% msg * first letter is V
IF %MYPASSWORD:~0,2% == %WW% msg * first letter is W
IF %MYPASSWORD:~0,2% == %XX% msg * first letter is X
IF %MYPASSWORD:~0,2% == %YY% msg * first letter is Y
IF %MYPASSWORD:~0,2% == %ZZ% msg * first letter is Z
```

nice cause this only covers the first character. if i had for instance 100 characters i would have to do the above 100 times over if i had 1000 1000x over (sory Im thinking this is idealy for loops, but i always have trouble with them)

in short im trying to loop to %MYPASSWORD:~998:2% if there were 1000 characters in the password or %MYPASSWORD:~99998:2% if there were a million. obviously nobody codes that amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your job becomes much easier if you reverse the definition of your character map variables. You use the letter as the name and the code as the value. I would use the code in the name, and the letter as the value. The name should be prefixed with a non-numeric character so that the parser does not get confuse something like `%17%` with the `%1` parameter.

For example, where you may have defined `set AA=21`, I would define `set map21=A`

The length of a batch variable is not unlimited - the maximum length is 8192 characters. Divide that by 2, and you have your max number of loops. The FOR /L command is a fast looping construct.

You will also benefit by using delayed expansion.

Here is all that is needed if you adopt the recommendations above:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "decodedPassword="
for /l %%N in (0 2 8191) do (
  for /f "delims=" %%C in ("!MYPASSWORD:~%%n,2!") do (
    set "decodedPassword=!map%%C!"
  )
)
```

The above code could be optimized further. For example, it wastes time continuing to look for more codes after it has processed the last one. But the amount of wasted time is probably inconsequential in your case.